# How to test a class method in rspec that returns a model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test my User model's class method `#registered_but_not_logged_in(email)`, which grabs the first user that matches the email that has a `confirmed_at` entry but has never logged in (which I'm counting with `sign_in_count`). I'm using rspec with Factorygirl, plus shoulda-matchers v2.8.

Here's the ruby:

```
def self.registered_but_not_logged_in email
  self.with_email( email ).confirmed.never_signed_in.first
end
```

I've tested this in the Rails console and I know it works as expected so it's not a logic problem on that end, so I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong in my test:

```
describe User do
  # create @user

  describe ".registered_but_not_logged_in" do
    it "returns a user that matches the provided email who is confirmed, but who has not yet signed in" do
      @user.confirmed_at = 2.days.ago
      @user.email = "fisterroboto5893@mailinator.com"

      result = described_class.registered_but_not_logged_in("fisterroboto5893@mailinator.com")
      expect(result).to be_instance_of(User)
    end
  end
```

In this example, `result` is nil. I know that this is a case of `@user` existing outside the database while the method is actively checking the DB, but I don't know how to handle this while using rspec/factorygirl. Any help is definitely appreciated!

Comment: Probably need a `@user.save` to persist the changes -- the implementation goes to the database, and skips any in-memory changes

Comment: @nort Adding `@user.save` doesn't change anything, unfortunately. `result` is still nil.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% sure why what I'm doing is working, but here's the solution that I stumbled across with the help of @nort and one of my coworkers:

```
it "returns a user that matches the provided email who is confirmed, but who has not yet signed in" do
  @user.confirmed_at = 2.days.ago
  @user.email = "fisterroboto5893@mailinator.com"
  @user.sign_in_count = 0
  @user.save!
  expect(User.registered_but_not_logged("fisterroboto5893@mailinator.com")).to be_instance_of(User)
end
```

What I believe is happening is the save! is saving @user to the test database, which is otherwise completely unpopulated as I develop against a different DB. The issue of course being that we can't test data that doesn't exist.

As a bonus, note that expect().to... is the preferred convention for rpsec. Also, `described_class` I believe would totally work fine, but am preferring explicitness right now since I'm still learning this stuff.